# django test redirection fail

Tags: django, unit-testing

i'm trying to write tests for my view functions and i encounter a problem.

i want to check that a specific function return me a json of some kind, so i

wrote the following code:

```
client = Client()
response = client.get('/func/1/True')
self.assertRedirects(response, "login/?next=/func/1/True", 302)
```

when the view function is:

```
@login_required
def func(request, objId, flag):
    return json.dumps(something)
```

but when i run the tests i get a failed from the assert:

```
ValueError: The file 'myApp/css/bootstrap.css' could not be found with
    <whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x0000000004C7A898>.
```

but when i run the app without tests it works find and finds the file.

note: i run the tests from eclipse (in case it makes a different...)

any ideas why it happen?

Comment: You're checking for `302` redirect. What if it's a `301`?

Comment: its 302. and it doesn't fail on this

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me when I disabled whitnoise for my tests. I did this by disabling STACTFILES_STORAGE in settings. You can do that for your tests with an @override_settings decorator like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
from django.test import Client

class ClientTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.c = Client()

    @override_settings(STATICFILES_STORAGE = None) # added decorator
    def test_client_works(self):
        resp = self.c.get('/some/page/')
        self.assertTrue(resp.status_code is 200)

    def tearDown(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without having to write the decorator on every single test/class method?

Comment: Yes.  You can decorate the class. At least with @override_settings. I'm not sure if it works with every decorator.